# Assigning Values to unsigned short* buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having issues assigning value to unsigned short* and unsigned char* buffers. The code looks something like this:

```
// Header File
unsigned short* short_buff;
unsigned char* char_buff;
```

```
// Implementation File
short_buff = new unsigned short[10];
memset(&short_buff, 0, 10);

char_buff = new unsigned char[10];
memset(&char_buff, 0, 10);

unsigned short sVal = 0;
unsigned char cVal = 0x0;

// All of these cause core dumps
short_buff[0] = sVal;
memcpy(&short_buff[0], &sVal, 2); // 2 bytes per unsigned short
std::cout << short_buff[0] << std::endl;

// All of these also cause core dumps
char_buff[0] = cVal;
memcpy(&char_buff[0], &cVal, 1); // 1 byte per unsigned char
std::cout << char_buff[0] << std::endl;


// Yet strangely these cause no issues
unsigned short s2Val = short_buff[0];
unsigned char c2Val = char_buff[0];
```

I am completely at a loss as to what is going on here and why.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memset(short_buff, 0, 10*sizeof(short));
```

and

```
memset(char_buff, 0, 10*sizeof(char));
```

Two mistakes, `&` is wrong, you should pass the value of the pointer to `memset` not the address of the pointer variable. (This version `memset(&short_buffer[0], ...);` also works).

Secondly `memset` counts bytes not elements, so you need to multiply the array size by the element size, use `sizeof` for that.

Strangely you got it more or less right with `memcpy` later on. Why not the same thing for `memset`?